# Docker: how to use entrypoint + CMD together

Tags: docker

I know the difference between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` but cannot solve myself my issue.

This is my `Dockerfile` for use `ansible` without install it.

```
FROM python:3.10.4-slim-buster
# Update and upgrade
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
# Install requirements
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-client sshpass
RUN pip install pip --upgrade
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["--version"]
```

And this is the `entrypoint.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e

cp -pr /ssh /root/.ssh
chown -R root:root /root/.ssh/config
ansible-playbook
```

So, I'm expecting that launching my Docker with

```
docker run \
    --rm -it \
    -v $(TOPDIR)/playbook:/playbook:ro \
    -v ~/.ssh:/ssh:ro \
    sineverba/ansible:latest
```

(so, without arguments or CMDs) I get the version of ansible in console. But nothing is returned or printed.

Neither if I add the right usage, that I thought it overwrites the `CMD` instruction

```
docker run \
    --rm -it \
    -v $(TOPDIR)/playbook:/playbook:ro \
    -v ~/.ssh:/ssh:ro \
    --name $(CONTAINER_NAME) \
    $(IMAGE_NAME):$(VERSION) \
    -i /playbook/inventory.yml /playbook/playbook.yml
```

But, If I remove the entrypoint and re-build with

```
FROM python:3.10.4-slim-buster
# Update and upgrade
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
# Install requirements
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-client sshpass
RUN pip install pip --upgrade
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["ansible-playbook"]
CMD ["--version"]
```

I get version in console / I can use ansible (well, no, 'because I need to change owner of SSH keys) but, apart of ssh trouble, I get my working docker.

So, how can I replace the entrypoint `ansible-playbook` with the sh entrypoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't do anything with any parameters it might get. You need to add the parameters to the `ansible-playbook` command in the script, like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e

cp -pr /ssh /root/.ssh
chown -R root:root /root/.ssh/config
ansible-playbook $@
```